# How can I add pandas "match" based on column list values and value in additional column?

Tags: python, pandas, list, conditional-statements, matching

I have a dataframe that contains a column with a list of identifiers called Multiple_IDS and a column called ID. Now, I would like to create an additional column called "Match" that tells weather an ID was contained in the Multiple_IDs column or not. The ouput should be an additional column called Match that contains True or False values. Here some sample input data:

```
data = {'ID':[2128441, 2128447, 2128500], 'Multiple_IDs':["2128442, 2128443, 2128444, 2128441", "2128446, 2128447", "2128503, 2128508"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The list has the datatype "object".

The desire output would then be this according to the input data provided above.

[image]

I know I can achieve this using explode and then comparing the values but I am wondering if there something more elegant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in` statement if is possible test without separate each `ID`:

```
df['Match'] = [str(x) in y for x, y in df[['ID','Multiple_IDs']].to_numpy()]
print (df)
        ID                        Multiple_IDs  Match
0  2128441  2128442, 2128443, 2128444, 2128441   True
1  2128447                    2128446, 2128447   True
2  2128500                    2128503, 2128508  False
```

Or:

```
df['Match'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x['ID']) in x['Multiple_IDs'], axis=1)
print (df)
        ID                        Multiple_IDs  Match
0  2128441  2128442, 2128443, 2128444, 2128441   True
1  2128447                    2128446, 2128447   True
2  2128500                    2128503, 2128508  False
```

Another idea is match by splitted values:

```
df['Match'] = [str(x) in y.split(', ') for x, y in df[['ID','Multiple_IDs']].to_numpy()]
```

---

```
df['Match'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x['ID']) in x['Multiple_IDs'].split(', '), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

What I will do

```
s=pd.DataFrame(df.Multiple_IDs.str.split(', ').tolist(),index=df.index).eq(df.ID.astype(str),axis=0).any(1)
Out[10]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
df['Match']=s
```